# How to use Spring Social Twitter in a desktop application?

Tags: twitter, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I'm currently experimenting with Spring Social Twitter and wonder how I could use it for a desktop application because you cannot provide a callback url.

Is there any possibility to use username and password for the authorization or a way to retreive the OAuth token without a callback url?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to retrieving the OAuth token is to run your own webservice which performs the OAuth dance on behalf of your application.

If you can run a web service which has a (public and fixed) callback url which you can tell twitter, then your desktop application can direct new users to this website to authenticate. Once the oauth dance is complete your desktop application can download the OAuth token from your webservice and use that from then on.